# Why can't I reference a primary key?

Tags: mysql

The first two tables successfully pass, but as soon as the mysql checker reach the third table, it informs me that there is a problem with the reference key.
Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE USER(
    Username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Picture VARCHAR(30),
    Points INT(5) DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
    Password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Firstname VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    Lastname VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Username)
);

CREATE TABLE THREAD (
    ThreadID INT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PostID int(9) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ThreadID)  
);

CREATE TABLE POST(
    ThreadID INT(9) NOT NULL,
    PostID INT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Content TEXT NOT NULL,
    NumberOfLines INT(5) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ThreadID, PostID),
    FOREIGN KEY ThreadID(ThreadID) REFERENCES THREAD(ThreadID)
);
```

The error I am getting is the following:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
    PRIMARY KEY(ThreadID, PostID),
    FOREIGN KEY fk_ThreadID(ThreadID) REFE' at line 6
```

I tried creating the `PRIMARY KEY(ThreadID, PostID)` as separate entities, but this doesn't seem to work.
Thank you.

Comment: I dont think you set ThreadID in front og parantesis in the FOREIGN KEY part.

Comment: @MattiasÅslund You can. It's the optional name of the index.

Comment: Are you sure this error message belongs that code …? When I test it in SQLfiddle, I get a different one: _“Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key”_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL isn't being terribly informative there.  SQLFiddle gives it straight.

> Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

<strike>You can't have a multi-column key where one of them is `AUTO_INCREMENT`</strike> The `AUTO_INCREMENT` column must be first in a multi-column key in an InnoDB table. Either remove `AUTO_INCREMENT` from `PostID`, or make `PostID` alone the `PRIMARY KEY` and protect a post from appearing in the same thread twice with `UNIQUE(ThreadID, PostID)`.

```
CREATE TABLE POST(
    PostID        INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ThreadID      INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Thread(ThreadID),
    Content       TEXT NOT NULL,
    NumberOfLines INT NOT NULL,

    UNIQUE(ThreadID, PostID)
);
```

UPDATE: The best answer is [@georgecj11's to put PostID first in the key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36533713/14660) as it only uses a single index.

Comment: You still can have autoincrement on multi column primary key:
 create table a ( id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, col2 varchar(10), primary key (id, col2)) engine=innodb;

Comment: @georgecj11 You are correct, and yours should be the accepted answer as it doesn't add an extra index.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Schwern, its giving error due to wrong usage of primary key. Below create table will work.

```
create table a ( 
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  col2 varchar(10), primary key (id, col2)
) engine=innodb;
```

So auto-increment column needs to be first one in the primary key.

We have extensively used this kind of primary key to partition the table on col2 - to range partition on a column, the column need to be part of primary key.

Also to mention, you can achieve additional unique key at the cost of an extra index

Comment: "So auto-increment column needs to be first one in the primary key" if you want to have only one key in this table as is. But in general, the `auto_increment` can be part of a composite A not left-most so long as it is a key unrelated to the composite A. That is if there was such a need.